# Conexión bluetooth en un fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Tengo un código para crear la conexión a un modulo bluetooth pero quiero incrustarlo en un fragment, espero alguien me pueda ayudar, este es el código:

```
Button IdEncender, IdApagar, IdDesconectar;
TextView IdBufferIn;

Handler bluetoothIn;
final int handlerState = 0;
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private StringBuilder DataStringIN = new StringBuilder();
private ConnectedThread MyConexionBT;
// Identificador unico de servicio - SPP UUID
private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
// String para la direccion MAC
private static String address = null;
//-------------------------------------------

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_luz);

    IdEncender = (Button) findViewById(R.id.IdEncender);
    IdApagar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.IdApagar);
    IdDesconectar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.IdDesconectar);
    IdBufferIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IdBufferIn);

    bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                DataStringIN.append(readMessage);

                int endOfLineIndex = DataStringIN.indexOf("#");

                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
                    String dataInPrint = DataStringIN.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                    IdBufferIn.setText("Dato: " + dataInPrint);
                    DataStringIN.delete(0, DataStringIN.length());
                }
            }
        }
    };

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); // get Bluetooth adapter
    VerificarEstadoBT();

    IdEncender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyConexionBT.write("a");
        }

    });

    IdApagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyConexionBT.write("b");
        }

    });

    IdDesconectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btSocket != null) {
                try {
                    btSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ;
                }
            }
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
    //crea un conexion de salida segura para el dispositivo
    //usando el servicio UUID
    return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Consigue la direccion MAC desde DeviceListActivity via intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //Consigue la direccion MAC desde DeviceListActivity via EXTRA
    address = intent.getStringExtra(DispositivosBT.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    //Setea la direccion MAC
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La creacción del Socket fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // Establece la conexión con el socket Bluetooth.
    try {
        btSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
        }
    }
    MyConexionBT = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    MyConexionBT.start();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try { // Cuando se sale de la aplicación esta parte permite
        // que no se deje abierto el socket
        btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
    }
}

//Comprueba que el dispositivo Bluetooth Bluetooth está disponible y solicita que se active si está desactivado
private void VerificarEstadoBT() {

    if (btAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "El dispositivo no soporta bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        } else {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
    }
}

//Crea la clase que permite crear el evento de conexion
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        int bytes;

        // Se mantiene en modo escucha para determinar el ingreso de datos
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                // Envia los datos obtenidos hacia el evento via handler
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Envio de trama
    public void write(String input) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(input.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //si no es posible enviar datos se cierra la conexión
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La Conexión fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola @CesarPerez, Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina para poder ganar tu primera medalla, y ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para hacer un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y la comunidad acepte de buena forma tu pregunta

Comment: hola amigos me encontré con su post, como quedo tu codigo finalmente? estoy atorado con el mismo problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que agregar onCreateView y actualizar los componentes referenciados desde la rootView que creaste.

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.UUID;


public class MainActivity extends Fragment {


    final Button IdEncender=null, IdApagar=null, IdDesconectar=null;
    final TextView IdBufferIn=null;

    Handler bluetoothIn;
    final int handlerState = 0;
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private StringBuilder DataStringIN = new StringBuilder();
    private ConnectedThread MyConexionBT;
    // Identificador unico de servicio - SPP UUID
    private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    // String para la direccion MAC
    private static String address = null;

    private View rootView = null;
//-------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                    DataStringIN.append(readMessage);

                    int endOfLineIndex = DataStringIN.indexOf("#");

                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
                        String dataInPrint = DataStringIN.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                        IdBufferIn.setText("Dato: " + dataInPrint);
                        DataStringIN.delete(0, DataStringIN.length());
                    }
                }
            }
        };


    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_luz, container, false);
        actualizarFragment_luz();

        return rootView;

    }

private void  actualizarFragment_luz(){

    IdEncender = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.IdEncender);
    IdApagar = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.IdApagar);
    IdDesconectar = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.IdDesconectar);
    IdBufferIn = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.IdBufferIn);


    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); // get Bluetooth adapter
    VerificarEstadoBT();

    IdEncender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyConexionBT.write("a");
        }

    });

    IdApagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyConexionBT.write("b");
        }

    });

    IdDesconectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btSocket != null) {
                try {
                    btSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ;
                }
            }
            finish();
        }
    });


}


    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
        //crea un conexion de salida segura para el dispositivo
        //usando el servicio UUID
        return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Consigue la direccion MAC desde DeviceListActivity via intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //Consigue la direccion MAC desde DeviceListActivity via EXTRA
        address = intent.getStringExtra(DispositivosBT.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        //Setea la direccion MAC
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La creacción del Socket fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Establece la conexión con el socket Bluetooth.
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
            }
        }
        MyConexionBT = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        MyConexionBT.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try { // Cuando se sale de la aplicación esta parte permite
            // que no se deje abierto el socket
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
        }
    }

    //Comprueba que el dispositivo Bluetooth Bluetooth está disponible y solicita que se active si está desactivado
    private void VerificarEstadoBT() {

        if (btAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "El dispositivo no soporta bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            } else {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

//Crea la clase que permite crear el evento de conexion
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        int bytes;

        // Se mantiene en modo escucha para determinar el ingreso de datos
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                // Envia los datos obtenidos hacia el evento via handler
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Envio de trama
    public void write(String input) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(input.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //si no es posible enviar datos se cierra la conexión
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La Conexión fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias pero me marca error en los getBaseContext y el finish de IdDesconectar.setOnClickListener

Comment: Utiliza una variable de modulo, `private Context mContexto=null;` y llenala en onCreate con `mContexto = getActivity();`. reemplaza getBaseContext() con mContexto.

Comment: Comenta el finish() y pruebalo.

Comment: Oh ya funciono muchisimas gracias encerio te lo agradezco :) me resolviste el problema.